# why does python require __init__.py to treat directories as containing packages?

Tags: python

While going through 6.4 Packages section of [python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) I came across the following line:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories
>   as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a 
>   common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules
>   that occur later on the module search path.

I understand that `__init__.py` is required to mark directories as containing packages, but I don't understand what it means by `prevent directories with a common name...from unintentionally hiding valid modules...`.

Could someone explain why the `__init__.py` is required?

Comment: Actually, as of Python 3.3, it doesn't any more. See PEP 420.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets say you had a project that contained a directory called `math` that contained some numerical data.  If no `__init__.py` were required, then when you did `import math`, it would try to import that directory instead of the real `math` module.  But since your directory just contained data and not actual Python code, the import would fail.  Thus your `math` directory would block you from importing the real `math` module from the standard library, even though your `math` directory doesn't contain Python code at all.

The `__init__.py` is like a confirmation, the directory saying "Yes, I really am a Python package, not just a directory full of files.  It makes sense to import me."  Any directories that don't "announce" themselves in this way are skipped over because Python knows they can't be imported.  This is good, because the Python standard library has modules with lots of common names (os, math, time, symbol, resource, etc.).  Without the `__init__.py` requirement, you would never be able to use any of those names for *any* directory on your Python path -- not even to store data or files unrelated to Python.

`string` is actually not the best example in this case.  There is a module called `string` but it is not so useful these days because most of its functions are available as methods on the `str` type.  But, like I mentioned, there are lots of other modules with common names.

Comment: I think a module like `json` would be better to use in this example, because Python's `math` module is a built-in and can't be overridden like this

Comment: still, you can get into trouble just by creating __init__.py in folder that has any of this 'special' name; Somehow all other languages can cope with this problem without need for having tens of useless __ini__ files

Answer (score 3):

You may have a folder in your source tree called string/ which contains localization data, but when you try and `import string` in your code, without `__init__.py`, Python would attempt to import this directory instead of the standard library module. While there are cases you may want to shadow standard library modules, having it happen by accident if you happen to use directories with names like http/, string/, os/ etc. would be problematic.